# Google Analytics 4 - How to Get Event Data via GA4 Reporting API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, universal-analytics

Previously, with Universal Analytics, it was possible to request goal data via API by specifying the **goal number**, for example:

`ga:goal01Completions`

In GA4, assuming the event has been 'marked as conversion', this can be replicated by specifying the **conversion name**, for example:

`conversions:online_enquiry`

However is there are generalised method in GA4 which can request the count of **any named event**, regardless of whether or not it has been marked as a conversion, for example:

`events:online_enquiry`

`events:page_view`

`events:begin_checkout`

`events:scroll`

`events:404_not_found`

Answer (score 0):

I used the `runReport` before.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport

It's creating a report. Dimension is `eventName`  and Metric might be `eventCount` or other you prefer.

Here is the list dimension and metric you can find

[Metric](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema#metrics)

[Dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema#dimensions)

But still open to better way maybe I don't know.

Comment: This could be a workaround, however I imagine I'd need to create a separate report for each event, then segment that report according to the dimension I'm interested in (e.g. source/medium). I'm wondering if there is a way to simply add my chosen event names as additional fields to any report, like what currently exists with the `conversions:conversion_name` metric.

Comment: If there are multiple event you want. You could add a filter to include them?